# Angular ng serve no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, angular, server, cli

Estoy intentando iniciar el servidor local con el comando `ng serve -o` pero solo muestra esto:

> Generating browser application bundles (phase: additional asset processing)

Antes tardaba un poco en iniciar pero ahora ya no inicia, solo se queda así.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Es muy útil también [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Usa ng serve para iniciar, el -o es para que una vez iniciado levante el navegador en localhost:4200, es posible que sea un problema con tu navegador